# Exercise from Kaplansky - Commutative Rings (1.2.3)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

**Exercise 3 in section 1-2:**

> Let $R$ be an integral domain, $P$ a finitely generated non-zero prime ideal in $R$, and $I$ an ideal in $R$ properly containing $P$.  Let $x$ be an element in the quotient field of $R$ satisfying $xI \subseteq R.$  Prove that $x$ is integral over $R$.  (Hint:  Observe that $IxP \subseteq P$ and deduce $xP \subseteq P$.)

**A theorem I use is:**

Theorem 12.  Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $T$ an $R$-algebra, $u \in T$.  The following statements are equivalent:
(a) $u$ is integral over $R$,
(b) there exists a finitely generated $R$-submodule $A$ of $T$ such that $uA \subseteq A$ and the left annihilator of $A$ in $T$ is $0$.

**Here is what I have for the proof so far.  I will mark what parts I have questions on with bolded numbers:**

First since $xI \subseteq R$, we see that $IxP \subseteq P$ since $P$ is an ideal.  Now suppose $xp \in xP \subseteq xI \subseteq R$.  So $xp = r$ for some $r \in R$.  Write $x = \frac{a}{b}$ for some $a,b \in R$ and $b \neq 0$.  Then $xp = r$ if and only if $ap = rb$.  Since $ap \in P$, then $rb \in P$.  Since $P$ is prime, $r \in P$ or $b \in P$.  If $r \in P$, then $xp \in P$ and we are done.  So suppose $b \in P$.

Since $I$ properly contains $P$, there is some $j \in I$ with $j \not \in P$.  Since $IxP \subseteq P$, then $jxp \in P$.  Let $\{p_1,...,p_n\}$ be a minimal set of generators for $P$.  Notice that $$jap_k = b(r_1p_1 + .... + r_n p_n)$$ for some $r_1,..,r_n \in R$.  That is, $$0 = br_1p_1 + ... + (ja-br_k)p_k + ... + r_np_n.$$  So $ja = br_k \in P$. **(1)**  So $j \in P$ or $j \in a$.  But $j \not \in P$ and so $a \in P$.

Now, $\frac{a}{b}p = r$ if and only if $ap = rb$.  So $b | a$ or $b|p$.  So since $a \in P$, we see that $\frac{a}{b}p \in P$.  **(2)** So $xp \in P$.  Therefore, $xP \subseteq P$.

**(3)** So I think I need to use theorem 12 here to get the result.  I think my submodule is my finitely generated ideal $P$ (viewed as an $R$-module).

**My questions/comments:**

(1):  I was sort of thinking of my ideal like a module.  Is this the correct approach here?  I specifically said minimal set of finite generators because I felt like otherwise what I said may not be true.  I'm not used to talking about finitely generated ideals.  I was trying to justify it myself, but the best explanation I had was that I was just thinking of it like an $R$ submodule of $R$.

(2):  I felt like I could word this better.  Essentially I am saying that the $b$ will "cancel" out and so we will have something in $P$ multiplied by something in $R$, which will of course be in $P$.  I haven't seen quotient fields too often, but I at least intuitively understand why it's true.

(3):  I am not sure in the last part what the $T$ would be in Theorem 12.  Is it the quotient field?  The reason I felt uneasy about this is because fields do not have ideals.  This is the only theorem that talked about something that would use $xP \subseteq P$. How should I word the conclusion of my proof?

I appreciate any help!  I am more or less working through this textbook on my own.  Working **all** of the exercises, so just trying to make sure I understand correctly =)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to assume that $P$ is finitely generated in order to show that $xP\subseteq P$. Let $p\in P$, and $j\in I-P$. Then $xp\in xP\subseteq xI\subset R$, so $xp\in R$. But from $IxP\subseteq P$ we get $j(xp)\in P$, so $xp\in P$.

Now apply the theorem for $T=\text{Quot}(R)$, and $A=P$.

Comment: That's a bit easier =P.  Don't know why I didn't think of that.  Thanks =P.